# I cant connect rediss with abp framework

Tags: redis, frameworks, abp

I use latest version ABP Framework tiered, EF and  blaozrserver client. I get redis error  It was not possible to connect to the redis server(s).
when treace AuthServerModule everything seems fine.
var redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect able to connect redis server and got database.
And my redis server work fine with redisInsight
2023-04-12 17:24:15.606 +03:00 [INF] Content root path: C:_MyProjectsa_Samples\Denemeler14\Adalim14\src\Adalim14.AuthServer
2023-04-12 17:24:15.668 +03:00 [INF] Request starting HTTP/2 GET https://localhost:44311/ - -
2023-04-12 17:24:22.411 +03:00 [ERR] It was not possible to connect to the redis server(s). UnableToConnect on merry-ladybug-33525.upstash.io:6379/Interactive, Initializing/NotStarted, last: NONE, origin: BeginConnectAsync, outstanding: 0, last-read: 5s ago, last-write: 5s ago, keep-alive: 60s, state: Connecting, mgr: 10 of 10 available, last-heartbeat: never, global: 0s ago, v: 2.2.4.27433
StackExchange.Redis.RedisConnectionException: It was not possible to connect to the redis server(s). UnableToConnect on merry-ladybug-33525.upstash.io:6379/Interactive, Initializing/NotStarted, last: NONE, origin: BeginConnectAsync, outstanding: 0, last-read: 5s ago, last-write: 5s ago, keep-alive: 60s, state: Connecting, mgr: 10 of 10 available, last-heartbeat: never, global: 0s ago, v: 2.2.4.27433
at StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.ConnectImplAsync(ConfigurationOptions configuration, TextWriter log) in /_/src/StackExchange.Redis/ConnectionMultiplexer.cs:line 861
at Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.StackExchangeRedis.RedisCache.ConnectAsync(CancellationToken token)
at Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.StackExchangeRedis.RedisCache.GetAndRefreshAsync(String key, Boolean getData, CancellationToken token)
at Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.StackExchangeRedis.RedisCache.GetAsync(String key, CancellationToken token)
at Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Distributed.DistributedCacheExtensions.GetStringAsync(IDistributedCache cache, String key, CancellationToken token)
at Volo.Abp.PermissionManagement.StaticPermissionSaver.SaveAsync()
at Volo.Abp.PermissionManagement.StaticPermissionSaver.SaveAsync()
at Castle.DynamicProxy.AsyncInterceptorBase.ProceedAsynchronous(IInvocation invocation, IInvocationProceedInfo proceedInfo)
at Volo.Abp.Castle.DynamicProxy.CastleAbpMethodInvocationAdapter.ProceedAsync()
at Volo.Abp.Uow.UnitOfWorkInterceptor.InterceptAsync(IAbpMethodInvocation invocation)
at Volo.Abp.Castle.DynamicProxy.CastleAsyncAbpInterceptorAdapter`1.InterceptAsync(IInvocation invocation, IInvocationProceedInfo proceedInfo, Func`3 proceed)
at Volo.Abp.PermissionManagement.AbpPermissionManagementDomainModule.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.<b__1>d.MoveNext()

Thanks for your advice

I tried connect my redis remote server with redisInsight client. All test seems fine.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am encountering an error in the AuthServerModule logs of the latest version of the Abp framework that says "It was not possible to connect to the Redis server(s)" even though Redis is showing a normal connection when I traced the issue. I have tried connecting to other remote Redis servers with the same result. However, I am able to connect to the Redis server using a client with the same parameters without any issues. When monitoring, I can see that the Abp framework is able to write and delete data from Redis.

Comment: Can you please reformat the question? It can be good to see the stack trace in a code section with indentation. Currently, it's hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure redis is running at `merry-ladybug-33525.upstash.io:6379`. If you are deploying to an isolated network, it can be the reason of your connection issues.

Also, check your application `appsettings.json` file for the **Redis**  section that has correct configuration like:

```json
"Redis": {
    "Configuration": "merry-ladybug-33525.upstash.io:6379"
  },
```